# shell script to add header to a file

Tags: shell, unix, vim, sed, awk

I was trying to write a script to add a trademark header to my .cpp file.
my solution is as follows.

```
cat trademark.txt test.cpp > new_test.cpp && mv new_test.cpp test.cpp
```

However, wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: What you're already doing is exactly the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use awk like this:**

```
awk 'NR==FNR && !h {print;h=1;} NR!=FNR{print}' headerFile mainFile > tmpFile
mv tmpFile mainFile
```

**Using vim/vi:**

```
vim +'0r headerFile|wq' mainFile 2>/dev/null
```

**Using GNU sed:**

```
sed -i.bak -e '2{x;G};1{h;rheaderFile' -e 'd}' mainFile
```

**Using non-GNU sed:**

```
HDR=$(head -1 headerFile) && sed -i.bak "1s/^/$HDR/" mainFile
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the nice way of using awk. however, it prints it to stdout but the "mainFile" doesn't get modified.

Comment: yes. i tried redirecting it to file. but in that case, it overwrites mainFile with headerfile

Comment: Use it like this: `awk 'NR==FNR && !h {print;h=1;} NR!=FNR{print}' headerFile mainFile > tmpFile && mv tmpFile mainFIle`

Comment: then it is similar to the solution I have mentioned in the question

Comment: @Jack: Yes that's correct, only difference being that this awk commands just reads 1 line from headerFile even if there are more than 1 lines.

Comment: @Jack: I added 2 better options using vi and sed. Pls check my edited answer.

Comment: vim option is great. However, second option only adds one line at the top of main file.

Answer (score 3):

You've already accepted an answer, but I'll suggest one more way:

```
sed -i -e '1r trademark.txt' -e '1{x;d;};2{H;g;}' test.cpp
```

Comment: Good one, somewhat similar to one I have: `sed -i.bak -e '2{x;G};1{h;rheaderFile' -e 'd}' mainFile`

Comment: I wanted to get rid of &&. And your answer precisely does that. thank you so much.

Comment: @Jack why do you want to get rid of the `&&`? Doesn't the approach you started with look an order of magnitude clearer than any of the suggestions you're getting?

Comment: @Jack - obviously you can in a couple dozen different way, but you simply shouldn't. Using `cat a b > c && mv c b` as you started with is exactly the right thing to do in this case for clarity, brevity, and robustness. Most, if not all, of the alternative solutions proposed are not only cryptic but have insidious caveats and can corrupt your original file.

Comment: Wasnt sure if concatenating to commands with && is a right thing or not. However, your opinion make sense to me.

Comment: @Jack - You asked the right question "is there a better way to do this", but unfortunately you got a lot of alternative but worse approaches in response instead of the correct answer which is simply "no". Your original approach will NOT corrupt your original file, every other one I've seen posted so far CAN corrupt your original file in rainy day scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vim, check out [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). It can do this, and *much* more.

E.g., I've defined the following snippet to add a public domain header to a file:

```
snippet pd "Public domain dedication" b
#
# Author: ${1:Roland Smith} ${2:<myemail@mydomain.com>}
# \$Date: `!v strftime("%F %T %z")` \$
#
# To the extent possible under law, $1 has waived all copyright and
# related or neighboring rights to `!v expand('%:t')`. This work is published 
# from the Netherlands. See http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/ 

endsnippet
```

To use this snippet, I insert `pd` at the beginning of a line in vim and hit `<tab>`. This expands the snippet, filling in the current date in the `$Date$` tag, and fills in the filename (using `expand`). It then highlights the name of the author which is the first variable, allowing me to change it if necessary. This automatically changes all further instances of that variable. Using `<ctrl>j` takes me to the following variable, the author's email address, which can also be changed if desired.

You can use vimscript commands (between quotes and prepended by `!v`). If your vim is compiled with Python support you can also use Python code with `!p`.